# Redis queue in lumen 5.5 not working / running

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, lumen

i try fount a lot of link in google, but until now it still not found a solution.

i want to make a queue with redis for sending mail.

in my .env, i set

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

in my route, i create sample link like this

```
$router->get('/email-with-queue', function () use ($router) {
  dispatch(new App\Jobs\EmailJob());
  return ['sending mail..'];
})
```

I create EmailJob in App\jobs

```
namespace App\Jobs;

class EmailJob extends Job{
  public function __construct()
  {
  }

  public function handle()
  {
    Mail::to("sendmailto@gmail.com")->send(new \App\Mail\CompleteOrder("Sending"));
  }
}
```

I create CompleteOrder.php on App\Mail

```
namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CompleteOrder extends Mailable
{
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

  public $order;

  public function __construct($order)
  {
    $this->order = $order;
  }

  public function build()
  {
    return $this->subject("Completed ".$this->order." | ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))->view("mail.mail");
  }
}
```

Now when i run `http://xxx.dev/email-with-queue`, it take 10s for sending mail.
when i run `php artisan queue:work` it still a blank

how to run queue in laravel. so when i run `http://xxx.dev/email-with-queue`, i just take 1s, but it send mail with queue.

Comment: is your redis is configured properly?

Comment: yes, when i test with ping result in redis is pong. i used in local
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

Comment: try to change a driver to database then and check whether it is job:work is working or not

Comment: Ohh god. this is my mistake, i create queue.php in config folder, and not load queue.php in bootstrap/app.php. after add $app->configure('queue');
code work like a charm. thanks @AdnanMumtaz

Comment: I have somewhat a similar problem: 'Class redis does not exist'
I have installed illuminate\redis and predis\predis. Also, the redis server is running but does not work. Any suggestions?